# Is there a simple way to spread units out without retreating in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a simple way to spread units out without retreating in StarCraft 2?

What I want here is to make it harder for splash damage to occur on units, but also easier to select my own units if they need to attack specific targets.  For instance, when attacking a structure with marines they will surround the structure in a some radius away from the structure.  Is there a way to form up this line before the engagement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way, no.

To natural AI forces your army to clump up so in order to get a quick concave you'll have to do it manually.

You simply need to practice the mouse movements to split your army. Precise boxing of a few of your units and clicking away to split your army is key to splitting.

There is a practice map on the NA servers that allows practice of marine splitting versus banelings. It is called Marine Split Challenge.